# Regex Match if string does not exist (multi-line)

Tags: regex

Trying to match if a word does NOT exist. I have done this before but am having issues trying to apply same concepts to my current `regex` pattern. The below pattern is from a cisco switch, which uses "!" as a separator between interfaces. The pattern matches if `vlan1` exists and contains "no shutdown" in its multi-line config block.

```
(?mi)vlan1[^\d][^!]*?((^.|^)no shutdown)
```

The issue is that I am trying to also match when the interface `vlan1` `config` block does NOT have the string "shutdown". This is required because both the "no shutdown" and the absence of "shutdown" (without "no") indicate that interface vlan1 is enabled.

For example, I am anticipating something similar to the below pattern, which does not work:

```
(?mi)vlan1[^\d][^!]*?(^.|^)(no shutdown|(?!shutdown))
```

The result should match ONLY if either "no shutdown" or the absence of "shutdown" exists.

See work here:
https://regex101.com/r/vhE3xm/1

Comment: What are the expected matches in the regex fiddle?

Comment: Try [`(?mi).*vlan1(?:\R(?! *shutdown|interface Vlan).*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/Qr8kJS/2).

Comment: Don't do that in one pattern, extract blocks, filter them with a test on "vlan1" and a test on "shutdown".

Comment: Apologies, the goal is to get no matches, as in my case, a match would mean that the configuration fails the audit (vlan1 is supposed to be shutdown). So if the given data matches, that means that interface vlan1 either has "no shutdown" OR is completely absent of the word "shutdown". In the pattern you provided, "vlan1" still matches even if the word "shutdown" (without a "no" in front) exists. If just the word "shutdown" exists (without a "no" in front) that means the configuration passed the audit, and the regex should not match anything.

Comment: if we reverse the logic, the goal becomes to take two match patterns, and combine into one "OR" pattern: 1. ( regex pattern to match when configuration block contains both "vlan1" AND "shutdown") OR 2. (regex pattern to match when no line contains "vlan1").

Comment: I figured it out, much thanks to @WiktorStribiżew for the assist. here is what I used: (?mi).*vlan1[^\d](?:(?!(.|\n)[^!]*(?<!no\W)shutdown))                             This will ONLY match if "vlan1" exists AND it does NOT contain "shutdown" in its script block (between two '!' symbols). I knew it would be a fairly simple solution. Any way you can optimize it? It currently takes awhile to complete.    https://regex101.com/r/gYTP6n/1

Comment: @livy111 The regex does not match anything.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You have to remove the word "shutdown". or any letter within it. My goal is for it NOT to match, because a match would be a fail in my audit.

Comment: Not sure how to optimize it. The usual construct to match a string in between two strings with no 3rd string in between is a tempered greedy token. See [this `(?mi)^.*vlan1\b(?:(?!\bvlan1\b|\bshutdown\b)[^!])*!` demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZws2q/2). I tried to unroll it, and only got [`(?mi)^.*vlan1\b.*(?:\R(?!.*vlan1\b| *shutdown\s*!).*?)*!`](https://regex101.com/r/rZws2q/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, much thanks to @WiktorStribiżew for the assist. here is what I used

```
(?mi).*vlan1[^\d](?:(?!(.|\n)[^!]*(?<!no\W)shutdown))
```

This will ONLY match if "vlan1" exists AND it does NOT contain "shutdown" in its script block (between two '!' symbols). I knew it would be a fairly simple solution. Any way you can optimize it? It currently takes awhile to complete. [regex101.com/r/gYTP6n/1](http://regex101.com/r/gYTP6n/1)

Note: You have to remove the word "shutdown". or any letter within it. My goal is for it NOT to match, because a match would be a fail in my audit

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the opposite logic: Check if the Vlan1 interface has been shut down properly:

[`(Vlan\d+)(?:(\n(\s(\[\w-=<>\])+)+)+)(?=\n\sshutdown)`](https://regex101.com/r/rFvOd5/1)

$1 contains Vlan1 if shutdown was found in the following block.

Comment: That is a valid pattern, and would work, except that on my Cisco routers no Vlan1 exists, so they all will fail the audit. Only alternative it seems to to audit the switches and routers separate.

Comment: So ideally, if we reverse the logic, the goal becomes to take two match patterns, and combine into one: 1. ( regex pattern to match when configuration block contains both "vlan1" AND "shutdown") OR 2. (regex pattern to match when no line contains "vlan1").